# How to use mailto with material ui?

Tags: material-ui, mailto

Trying to find how to use mailto in material UI. I tried just using a simple  tag within a ListItem, I tried using

`<ListItem button component={Link} mailto='' />`

I also tried

```
<ListItem button >
   <i class="material-icons mail_outline">mail_outline</i>
   <ListItemText primary="Support" />
  <a href="mailto:name@email.com"></a>
</ListItem>
```

I tried to find information about this on material-UI's website & Github but nothing. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 10):

I based mine on @Gary Vernon Grubb's answer, and added it into a button.

```
<Button
   variant="contained"
   size="large"
   color="primary"
   target="_top"
   rel="noopener noreferrer"
   href={`mailto:test@example.com`}
>
   <Typography variant="button" style={{ fontSize: '0.69rem' }}>
      Send Documents
   </Typography>
</Button>
```

Comment: How does one open the mailto in a new tab?

Answer (score 7):

If you set the component equal to `a` (the hyperlink tag), you can then use the `href` attribute to set the e-mail.

Thus, you'll get the following line.

```
<ListItem button key="Email" component="a" href="mailto:name@email.com">
```

Answer (score 3):

Mailto is a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) scheme for email addresses. It is used to produce hyperlinks on websites that allow users to send an email to a specific address without first having to copy it and enter it into an email client.

```
<ListItem>
   <a href="mailto:someone@example.com" target="_top">Send Mail</a>
</ListItem>
```

Above code works well for me in ReactJs with Material-UI library included.

Comment: How does one open the mailto in a new tab?

Answer (score 3):

This is how I do it with material-ui:

```
    <FormControlLabel
        control={
            <a target="_top"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
                href="mailto:test@example.com">
                <IconButton color="primary">
                    <EmailOutline /> {/* icon */}
                </IconButton>
            </a>
        }
        label={"test@example.com"}
        labelPlacement="end"
    />
```

Comment: How does one open the mailto in a new tab?